# How to let selenium edit an element

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I currently am writing a script for web automation but I want the program to edit an element for me here's a sample of the code I'm using

`final = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Change profile name')]")`
`final.click()`

now it won't click it since the website has the element set it false so I want selenium to edit and make the element true so it can click it, is that possible by any chance and if so can anyone explain and thanks!

Heres what the elements HTML look like

```
button class="btn btn-disabled" type="submit" data-testid="ChangeNameButton" aria-describedby="changeNameFormError" aria-disabled="true" data-bi-type="button">Change profile name
```

so instead of btn disabled, I want it to change it to enabled then click it and thanks in advance for any help submitted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you are trying to click is `disabled` and you can enable it with JS.

Something like this:

```
final = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Change profile name')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('className', 'btn-enabled');", final)
```

Comment: final = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Change profile name')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('className:btn btn-enabled;')", final)  i used this but i got an error

Comment: @EslamAli Sorry I had a syntax problem... I fixed it try again

Answer (score 0):

To change the text of an element do something like the following:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('theelement').innerHTML = 'changed text';");
```

To change or set attribute of element:

```
element =  driver.find_element_by_class_name("NAMEOFELEMENT"); 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('color: blue;')", element);
```

Comment: im not changing the text of the element rather editing it for example the common scenario when a website has your password as ***** so you change the element to text so you are able to see your password is there any way i can tell selenium to do that?

Comment: Ah, you would do this second option then which is the following:

Comment: final = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Change profile name')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('type: text;')", final);

Comment: You would have to change the text field not the button, I put the wrong element down

Comment: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present. i got this error when i ran this code                                                          :     final = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Change profile name')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('className:btn btn-enabled;')", final)